# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.api.OffsetRequest

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

I am getting error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException kafka.api.OffsetRequest while trying integrate Kafka to our Storm topology.
What versions you are running and it is working?
My pom.xml

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.2-incubating</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-kafka</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.2-incubating</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally I solved it by implementing my own Kafka SPOUT (reusing example code) with this dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.9.2</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.1.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can successfully use kafka.api.OffsetRequest with the following sample topology (KafkaSpoutTestTopology) in a Docker cluster:
https://github.com/wurstmeister/storm-kafka-0.8-plus-test
The topology uses storm-kafka version 0.9.3.
Note: "fig" command is replaced with "docker-compose" command.

EarliestTime() and LatestTime() method work fine.